# Combinatorics: Rotate 110 People 5 times

Tags: combinatorics

I'm throwing an event where we want 110 guests (n=110) to rotate through different tables. Guests will spend a few minutes at a table, and then at a given time they'll all get up and move to a different table, however they must be in a different group of guests at their next table. This will happen 5 times total. We have the following constraints

- 110 rotating guests
- 17 tables total
- Guests rotate 5 times (5 rounds)
- Guests should for the most part be with different guests at each new table they go to.
- 8 of the tables seat 7; 9 of the tables seat only 6.

I've been able to work this out on a small scale (5 tables x 4 guests/ table), but I can't work it out on the larger scale. It'd also be best if there was an easy way to explain this to the guests (e.g. give everyone a number and tell them to do a simple math calc to find their new table).

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: $8\cdot7+9\cdot6=110$. Are we to assume that the $22$ guests left standing in each round will mingle with each other?

Comment: My apologies - total rotating guests is 110. I've edited the above.

Comment: As each person only encounters at most 30 of the 109 other guests, a random draw should not have too much overlap

Comment: *Gulp.* That’s a lot of queasy people.

Answer (score 1):

Have $17$ tables with seat numbers from $0$ to $6$ (or, if a seat number $0$ seems too geeky or you don't want to privilege anyone by not having to get up during the rotation, use $1$ to $7$). In each rotation, everyone advances by as many tables as their seat number tells them and takes the seat with the same seat number at that table. Since $\gcd(7,17)=1$, it would take $17$ rotations before two people are at the same table again.

$9$ (different) seats will be empty in each round. If you don't want to have to move chairs between tables, use seat numbers $0$ to $6$ and give the empty chairs the seat number $0$. The scheme has the added benefit that if there are people whom you'd never want to have at the same table, it's very easy to arrange that by giving them the same seat number :-)

Comment: That's a great explanation, Joriki. We're nearly there, except for the issue that some tables seat 7 and some tables seat only 6. Using your method, I show that after each round we'll have some people showing up to their table only to find there are no more seats (ex: Number tables 1-17; tables 1-8 seat 7, tables 9-17 seat 6. After the first switch, the individual from table 2, seat 7, will move to table 9 (2+7) and look for seat 7, which won't exist).

Comment: @Kevin: I may have confused you by switching between using seat numbers $1$ to $7$ and $0$ to $6$. The $1$ to $7$ version would only work if you have $17$ tables with enough space for $7$ people each, and the $9$ empty spots could move around (as if they were invisible guests playing along). If you really only have space for $6$ seats at some of the tables, then you need to use the version with seat numbers $0$ to $6$ and assign the non-existent seats the number $0$. Then the invisible guests on the non-existent seats will stay put, and you'll never need more space or chairs than you have.